# How can I hide a div if all of the list items inside it equal &nbsp;?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have data being pulled from a content management system being displayed in unordered lists  There are 3no. `<ul>` sat inside a `<div>` with a class of plant.  There are multiple divs with `class="plant"` on the page.  After reading up on javascript I've decided that jquery is the way to go due to browser support etc.  If there is no data in the database then the CMS just puts a `&nbsp;` in the list item.

I want to achieve the following:  If all the list items inside the div are `&nbsp;` then hide the div.  Otherwise just hide the list items that have content in them.

I've managed to hide the list items with `&nbsp;` like so (thanks to another question on stackoverflow):

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '' && $(this).children().length == 0
})
.remove()
```

But the hiding of the divs if ALL of the li's are `&nbsp;` is proving more difficult.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.plant {
border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="plant">
<h3>Header 1</h3>
<ul class="attPlant">
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<h3>Header 2</h3>
<ul class="nonAttPlant">
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<h3>Header 3</h3>
<ul class="attPlant">
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="plant">
<h3>Header 1</h3>
<ul class="attPlant">
    <li class="item">TEST</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<h3>Header 2</h3>
<ul class="nonAttPlant">
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<h3>Header 3</h3>
<ul class="attPlant">
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
    <li class="item">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
</body>
<html>
```

Here is the Jquery I have so far:

```
$('.plant').each(function() {
var $this = $(this),
    $items = $this.children.children('.item');

        $items.each(function() {
            var x = true,
            $that = $(this).text();
                if ($that == '&nbsp;') {
                } else {
                    x = false;
                    break;
                }   
        });
        if (x = true) {
            $this.hide();
        }
});
```

I am new to jquery so the code above is probably horribly wrong.  I think that for each `<div>` I need to put all the list items into a variable, then loop through them and check if they equal `&nbsp;`.  If they don't then hide the `<div>`.  It isn't working in its current form but I don't know enough about jquery to figure out why.

I have searched and although there are numerous questions relating to hiding of divs, they are all different from my scenario.

Please can someone help?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; an `<h3>` cannot be wrapped directly within a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`); if you must have the heading within the list, it must be wrapped inside of an `<li>`, the *only* valid child of either a `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: Do you have control over the code that generates the html? I would suggest to check there before rendering the code if you do, as you can apply extra classes to the div if your conditions are met. There's also a typo on your markup. You should wrap your `<h3>` with `<li>` to make it valid.

Comment: Thanks guys.  No idea how I missed that, have updated the code above to make the html valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest simply filtering within a filter:

```
// selecting the div.plant elements, and filtering the collection:
$('div.plant').filter(function (){
    // caching the <li> descendants:
    var lis = $(this).find('li');

    // if the number of <li> descendants is equal to the number
    // of <li> elements whose trimmed text is equal to an
    // empty string:
    return lis.length === lis.filter(function(){
             return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';
           }).length;
// we hide those div.plant elements that are retained by the filter:
}).hide();
```

Although, honestly, while this works it seems redundant to do this client-side, when the server could, assuming it's generated dynamically, simply prevent the empty `<li>` elements from being generated. Or, rather than using `&nbsp;`, if you allowed an empty list-element (`<li></li>`, rather than `<li>&nbsp;</li>`) you could use a CSS selector as part of your jQuery. This could take the same approach, but be a little more concise:

```
$('div.plant').filter(function(){
    var lis = $(this).find('li');
    return lis.length === lis.filter(':empty').length;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Many thanks David.  This works perfectly.  To answer your questions, I don't have access to the server side (apart from uploading and editing html and css files) unfortunately.  The data is getting pulled from the database using the following mark up %(table#_field#)s, there is also some javascript involved but I have no idea how it works.